# How to make a query in sphinx like the normal LIKE operator "%somestring%"

Tags: mysql, sphinx

I am using sphinx and want to search items that contains a first text AND contains other text in other column.

I have tried this: @Name na @LastName test

But it only return the string that match exactly both words, I want results like.

Name Test1, Name test2, OtherName lastnametotest,

Any help will be really appreciated,

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You could use OR operator for first matches

SELECT * FROM YOUR_INDEX WHERE MATCH ('(@name test1 | test2) @othername lastnametotest');

Comment: You don't know the results until you run the query so it makes no sense to create a query for known results....